# Display result from google places in an ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am integrating into google places in order to get a list of places within a certain radius. The code I have works however it is just displaying the list which is giving me a problem. I need the list of places in an array so that I can display it on the HTML page. Currently, it's using document.getElementByID which does not work well with ionic.

```
getRestaurants(){
    var request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lon),
        radius: '50000',
        types: [this.category]
    };

    var places = document.getElementById('results');
    //remove the above line
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(places);
    //replace places above (places) with a variable that will be called in the html page eg. items
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                places.innerHTML += results[i].name + '<br/>';
                //change above to this.items = results[i].name
                console.log(results[i].name);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: How does this code currently integrate with Ionic? Will this be used in a page, service...?

Comment: the above code is in a page.ts and it executes in page.html, so no service being used

Comment: okay i fixed it, just needed to replace places with a global variable that can be read in the html page, will update

Comment: "global variable" sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: yes can be local too, works as well, just tested it